# Error: Longer object lengths is not a multiple of short object, in R when filtering data

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to filter my data set to only include certain values in R using the tidyverse package.

My code is:

```
library(tidyverse)
filtereddata = ogdata %>%
  filter(month == c("January", "April", "July", "August"))
```

The original data is called ogdata and the subsetted data should be filtereddata. I am trying to filter the column "month" to only include 4 of the 12 months in filtereddata. The data has 15418 observations and 38 columns. When I run my code, I get the following error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

I am unsure what this means and how to fix this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` when the length of the vector to be compared is greater than 1

```
library(dplyr)
ogdata %>%
      filter(month %in% c("January", "April", "July", "August"))
```